# How to use INNER JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I am new in PHP. I have a sql query. I use INNER Join. I face some problem in it. If there is any single blank field is empty it does not display any data of other field.

Here is my Query

```
$sql= "SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle
FROM og_ratings r 
INNER JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
INNER JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
INNER JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
INNER JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
INNER JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
INNER JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= '$id2'
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: Replace all your `inner join` with `left join` and put `og_companies` first in the list, so you will keep all companies.

Comment: ofcourse.. inner join will only get data with similar column value on each tables. in your case use left join or right join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therefore, you have `LEFT JOIN` (or `RIGHT JOIN` in some special cases). `LEFT JOIN` just selects all from the first table specified, and fills fields from other tables - where no entry is found - with `NULL`.

Just replace all your `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`

```
$sql= "SELECT r.client_id,c.id,t.id,a.id,o.id,c.name as cname,t.title as ttitle,a.title as atitle,o.title as otitle, l.title as ltitle
FROM og_ratings r 
LEFT JOIN og_companies c
ON r.client_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN og_rating_types t
ON r.rating_type_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN og_actions a
ON r.pacra_action = a.id
LEFT JOIN og_outlooks o
ON r.pacra_outlook = o.id
LEFT JOIN og_lterms l
ON r.pacra_lterm = l.id
LEFT JOIN og_sterms s
ON r.pacra_sterm = s.id
WHERE c.id= '$id2'
ORDER BY r.id DESC
LIMIT 1 ";
```